# getting error while using logcat for checking logs of an app in linux

Tags: adb, logcat, android-logcat, buildozer, usb-debugging

I want to know bugs of my android app so i tried to use logcat to see its log and followed these steps:-

```
You need to use adb server.
1. Connect your android with your laptop/pc 
2. Go to developer options and turn on the stay awake and USB debugging options. (Your phone) 
3. In your terminal, type "sudo adb kill-server" and then "sudo adb start-server".
4. Type "adb devices" (this should give list of devices connected)
    List of devices attached 
    you_device_name device

5. "cd" to your folder where you have made your build.
6. Type "buildozer android debug deploy run logcat > logcat.txt"
this saves the logs (for the entire process) in a file logcat.txtx in the same folder and also deploys you app on the phone.
Go through it and find your error.
7. keep your phone awake.(do not lock it).
```

But when i run the 6th step, a time comes it says:-

```
error: device 'adb' not found
- waiting for device -
```

i have searched many times on the internet and when finally i am posting here to get solution

Comment: what happens when you run `adb  devices`? does your device detect with correct permissions? can you please post the output ?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh  this is the result:-      root@kali:~# adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
efeb26190903 device

Comment: nice, and you are positive that you have enabled usb debugging and dismissed the RSA fingerprint popup on the device right ? If so, what happens when you connect the device and run `adb logcat` ?

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh when running adb logcat continous logs comes or any data,and yes i enabled usb debugging and not sure about RSA fingerprint popup

Comment: But i am doing step number 6 given above

Comment: ok, this sounds like a bulldozer specific problem. So connect your device, make sure it is detected, then type `adb shell`. You would now be logged in to your device's shell. type a random adb command like `adb devices` in the device shell to start the device adb demon. (yes such a thing exists). This would have manually started the adb process on your phone. repeat step 6 in your instructions and see if that works :). Otherwise I can;t say for sure

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh when i enters to the shell after following your command and type random command as u said adb devices, it says:- /system/bin/sh: adb: not found. ANd thanx srinivas for helping me, i was looking for someone's help on this since 3 days

Answer (score 0):

I actually initially misread the bulldozer error. It is complaining that a device `adb` doesn't exist. Which is strange. It should have picked up the device serial instead.

You could theoretically force adb commands to go to your device by executing
`export ANDROID_SERIAL= <your device's serial number>`

you could now repeat the steps and check if this works.

Also just for completeness just check if there exists an `adb` binary in the system partitin of your device.

Also make sure you haven't missed out any bulldozer init steps

Comment: thanks for your support but this solution that you gave didn't worked